# How to parse Google Protocol Buffers that in the direct memory without allocating heap byte array in Java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, netty, protocol-buffers, bytebuffer

I'm trying parse a ByteBuf that is not in the JVM heap, to Google Protocol Buffer object. In fact it's the direct memory byte buffer which Netty passed to me.

This is what I am currently doing:

```
ByteBuf buf = ...;
ByteBufInputStream stream = new ByteBufInputStream(buf);
Message msg = MyPbMessage.getDefaultInstance().getParserForType().parseFrom(stream);
```

This can work. However, I found this type of parsing introduce new byte array per message, and cause a lot GC.

So is there a way to avoid these in heap byte arrays creating? i.e, parse Google Protocol Buffer bytes directly from native memory.

Comment: You might try storing _one_ on-heap byte array and copying each of Netty's ByteBufs to it, rather than letting the protobuf parser allocate a new one for each message?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, it's doable. I just used a ThreadLocal<byte[]> as the on-heap cache for each message's bytes, and it runs well. However, I think there's also a side effect that the size of the cache, i.e the byte array in the ThreadLocal, can only be greater and greater, not adjustable. And if I make the cache's size exactly the message's bytes size, what difference does it make with the allocating new one each time?

Comment: you can let it grow but also store it in a thread local -> soft/weak reference so it'll get GCed and you can start over from a small one

Comment: What if you do `parseFrom(buf.array())`? Or does this `ByteBuf` not have a backing array? Note that no matter what you do here, protobuf itself still does lots of allocation internally.

Comment: @KentonVarda This ByteBuf does not have a backing array since it is in the direct memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it [the way the Guava guys do](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/escape/Platform.java) store a small buffer (1024 bytes) in a ThreadLocal, use it if it suffices and never put a bigger buffer in the TL.

This'll work fine as long as most requests can be served by it. If the average/median size is too big, you could go for soft/weak reference, however, without some real testing it's hard to tell if it helps.

You could combine the approaches, i.e., use a strongly referenced small buffer and a weakly referenced big buffer in the TL. You could pool your buffers, you could...

*... but note that it all has its dark side. Wasted memory, prolonged buffer lifetime leading to promoting them to the old generations, where garbage collecting is much more expensive.*

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this is the only way to solve the problem, without switching to another protocol that supports zero copy. Workable, but not much elegant.